# text content in <td> wraps fine in browser, but not PDF

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, pdf, wicked-pdf

I am using WickedPdf to generate PDFs from HTML.  In the browser, everything looks great:

[image: Browser screenshot]

But, when I go to render it with WickedPdf, the content overflows into the neighboring td:

[image: WickedPdf screenshot]

I've read a few posts about fixed tables, but they don't seem to help:

```
table, table td {
   table-layout:fixed;
   word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Comment: I am not sure about `WickedPdf` but `pdfkit` seems to work just fine and very simple to setup as it uses `wickedpdf` in the backend along with some wrapper.

Comment: thanks for your reply, tried pdfkit, same deal: http://i.imgur.com/l5t2XsT.png

Comment: May be you can try changing the size to A3 to fix the spacing issue here.

Comment: something like this: `PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.default_options = {
    encoding: 'UTF-8',
    page_size: 'A3',
    print_media_type: true
  }
end`

Comment: thanks again, tried this, same result

Comment: tried the PDFKit.configure comment, same result http://i.imgur.com/kgxpV3t.png

Comment: could you please post the html code in the question. there might be something wrong with the alignment.

Comment: sure, and thank you for your time helping with this, here is the HTML: https://gist.github.com/kevinchugh/17a88a50e2743394d6e52740ac517124

Comment: I think there is some issue with the classes you are applying to your table. you have used `class=text-center` for table header but in your table body you have pushed text to left `<td class="text-left" width="33%">` and then you have passed a div option with `<div style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">`, break word would happen automatically if using bootstrap table anyway. And yes I think WickedPDF as well as Pdfkit both of them has issues with `div` tag. try not to use it inside table. hope that helps

Comment: thanks for your help again, removed the div in the td, removed text-center and text-left, removed width, same issue.  i wonder if this is a general bootstrap issue.

Comment: If I am not wrong this issue only occurs when you try to convert page to pdf but not when you simply try to view the page is it?

Comment: yes, you are correct.  you can emulate this by simply opening the HTML in a browser and print it to PDF if you have a PDF printer driver.  You can see that the html renders and wraps the text in the <td> perfectly in the browser, but in the PDF print preview it overflows and collides with the neighboring td:  http://i.imgur.com/IX4bnGJ.png

Comment: that is very strange behavior man. I hope its not happening due to chrome cause lot of people have complained about it in the past. and the suggested solution is the same you tried doing earlier `.the-table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
`

Comment: really sorry man but I am not able to figure out what exactly causing this issue. hard luck

Comment: @Abhinay I am so grateful for your help, thank you so much.  I will keep trying.

Comment: @Abhinay here's a clue.  If you go to the original source of the HTML, where they preview it in an iframe (http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/V7E5b), and you replace their short text with long text, it prints fine http://i.imgur.com/cx9jJcQ.png  I'm wondering if this has something to do with the meta tag <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: Is this on chrome ? I have a gut feeling that it's happening because of chrome. Can you please test it on Firefox

Comment: it is on chrome, but my point is, that it works on chrome when it's in the preview iframe, i will test on firefox.

Comment: tested on chrome, there is no built in PDF printing in chrome, but my code (not the iframe code) shows the same issue in FF.

Comment: here's another clue.  if you take the original page (http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/V7E5b), and just look at the iframe directly (http://bootsnipp-env.elasticbeanstalk.com/iframe/V7E5b), modify the text in the td to be long, and go to print it, you get the same error in wrapping.  so this has something to do with the size of the container iframe i think.

Comment: even weirder, if i create an iframe, and set it to a fixed width, and include the other html, it renders fine now: http://i.imgur.com/vLTuHKg.png code is <iframe src = "invoice.html" width="900px" height="100%"/>

Comment: Yeah this seems to be very weird.

Answer (score 0):

`white-space: pre-wrap;` works for me

```
table td {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```